# How to have multiple radio buttons with different functionality?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am working on a project in which I need to make an HTML page with couple of radio buttons.

- First radio button is, `INSERT`. As soon as I click INSERT radio button, I would like to show three text box just below the INSERT radio button. First textbox is `datacenter`, second textbox is `node` and third textbox is `data`.
- Second radio button is, `UPDATE`. As soon as I click UPDATE radio button, I would like to show same above three text box just below the UPDATE radio button.
- Third radio button is, `DELETE`. As soon as I click DELETE radio button, I would like to show only one text box just below the DELETE radio button. In this one text box will be `node`.
- Fourth radio button is, `PROCESS`. As soon as I click PROCESS radio button, I would like to show four text box just below the PROCESS radio button. In this first textbox will be `datacenter`, second textbox will be `node`, third textbox will be `conf` and fourth textbox will be `data`.

I am able to make first two radio button work (insert and update) but somehow I am not able to understand how do I make last two radio button work.

Below is my HTML

```
<form method="post" action="testOperation">
    <input type="hidden" name="name" id="dynamicName">
    <input class="changeAction" type="radio" name="tt" value="Insert" div-id="insert"/> Insert
    <div id="insert" class="changeable"></div>
    <br/> <input class="changeAction" type="radio" name="tt" value="Update" div-id="update"/> Update
    <div id="update" class="changeable"></div>
    <br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Below is my jquery -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".changeAction").on("click", function(){
        $('.changeable').html('')
        var divId = $(this).attr("div-id");
        $("#dynamicName").val(divId);
        divId = "#"+divId;
        var myInput = '<label for="Datacenter"> Datacenter </label> <input type="text" name="datacenter" size="20" />  <label for="Node"> Node </label> <input type="text" name="node" size="20" /> <label for="Data"> Data </label> <input type="text" name="data" size="100"/>'
        $(divId).html(myInput);
    })
})
```

And here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7CDrL/). It will be of great help if anyone can provide any jsfiddle example?

Comment: Why radio buttons? Is there no other way to do this?

Comment: @Luxelin: hmmm.. Can you suggest other options? I was able to come up with this design only.. If you have better options, can you suggest something?

Comment: What is the overall goal here? I understand what you want with the radio buttons, but what is this being use for?

Comment: Overall goal is to pass the corresponding values of the textbox depending on which radio button is clicked to spring mvc controller method after we press submit button.. Suppose, if I am clicking INSERT radio button, then I need to pass those three text box values to spring mvc controller method.. And if I am clicking delete radio button, then I need to pass the node text box value as it has only node text box to same spring mvc controller method and same with other radio button. So that's why I was setting up my HTML form first then I can go to spring controller stuff.

Comment: Why not make a general layout—`datacenter`, `node`, `data`, etc.—and have buttons above it? So you just type whatever you want and then click, say, `insert` to insert that information. This way the user could type in the information then click the function he wants to apply.

Comment: In my case, I have different command like insert, update, delete.. Depending on whether it is insert or update or delete, I will perform insert or update or delete.

Comment: I did [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Luxelin/4Nmqk/) in just a few seconds. Maybe something like this where, depending on what they click, different input options are available. Using radio controls just seems clumsy to me. Using a form with buttons seems like a better idea, if you ask me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49286/discussion-between-ssh-and-luxelin)

Comment: If anything, just use buttons and write a function that customizes a form for each one. It will be easier for a user to understand, at least. Radio controls aren't meant for what you're trying to get them to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code in javascript part,

```
var datacenter = '<label for="Datacenter"> Datacenter </label> <input type="text" name="datacenter" size="20" />';
var node = '<label for="Node"> Node </label> <input type="text" name="node" size="20" />';
var data = '<label for="Data"> Data </label> <input type="text" name="data" size="100"/>';
var config = '<label for="Config"> Config </label> <input type="text" name="config" size="100"/>';

$(".changeAction").on("click", function () {
    var divId = $(this).attr("div-id");
    $('.changeable').html('');
    $("#dynamicName").val(divId);

    switch (divId) {
        case 'insert':
            //insert stuff goes here!!
            divId = "#" + divId;
            var myInput = datacenter + node + data;
            $(divId).html(myInput);
            break;
        case 'update':
            //update stuff goes here!!
            divId = "#" + divId;
            var myInput = datacenter + node + data;
            $(divId).html(myInput);
            break;
        case 'Delete':
            //Delete stuff goes here!!
            divId = "#" + divId;
            var myInput = node;
            $(divId).html(myInput);
            break;
        case 'process':
            //process stuff goes here!!
            divId = "#" + divId;
            var myInput = datacenter + node + config + data;
            $(divId).html(myInput);
            break;
    }
});
```

**SEE FIDDLE [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/7CDrL/6/)**

Comment: What does your jsfiddle do? It just pop up the alert box.. If you see my question, it has four radio button and your has only two.. And also no text box are getting show below the radio button. Or may be you haven't added the full code in the jsfiddle? If possible can you provide an example for that as well in your fiddle?

Comment: I updated my answer... here is the demo fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/cjramki/7CDrL/7/

Answer (score 0):

Change your html code to this

```
        <input class="changeAction" type="radio" name="tt" value="Insert" div-id="insert"/> Insert
    <div id="insert" class="changeable"></div>
    <br/> <input class="changeAction" type="radio" name="tt" value="Update" div-id="update"/> Update
    <div id="update" class="changeable"></div><br/>
    <input class="changeAction" type="radio" name="tt" value="Delete" div-id="delete"/> Delete
    <div id="delete" class="changeable"></div>
    <br/> <input class="changeAction" type="radio" name="tt" value="Process" div-id="process"/> Process
    <div id="process" class="changeable"></div>

        <br/>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Can you provide any jsfiddle example if possible?