# How to show certain texbox depending on which button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jsp

I am working on a project in which I need to make an HTML page with couple of radio buttons.

- First button is, `INSERT`. As soon as I click INSERT button, I would like to show three text box just below the INSERT button. First textbox is `datacenter`, second textbox is `node` and third textbox is `data`.
- Second button is, `UPDATE`. As soon as I click UPDATE button, I would like to show same above three text box just below the UPDATE button.
- Third button is, `DELETE`. As soon as I click DELETE button, I would like to show only one text box just below the DELETE button. In this one text box will be `node`.
- Fourth button is, `PROCESS`. As soon as I click PROCESS button, I would like to show four text box just below the PROCESS button. In this first textbox will be `datacenter`, second textbox will be `node`, third textbox will be `data` and fourth textbox will be `conf`

And lasttly there will be submit button which I will be pressing.

I am able to come up with this design in the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/8/)

**Problem Statement:-**

But somehow, few things are not working such as `Submit` button is not getting shown when I click Process button for the first time. Meaning for the first time, if you click Process button, then it shows only three textbox which is datacenter, node and data but in general it should show four textbox as shown above. And also submit button is not shown as well.

It will be of great help if anyone can provide jsfiddle example?

And also is there anything wrong I am doing in my jsfiddle which I should not be doing? Meaning instead of hiding the elements, I should delete them?

I am following up on previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22265319/how-to-have-multiple-radio-buttons-with-different-functionality/). In my previous question, my design was something else but after that I was able to come up with my new design as shown in my jsfiddle above.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/9/

Comment: it shows only three text box when I click Process button for the first time, instead it should show four as shown in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We talked about it some in a discussion and came up with http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmqk/12/

It's simpler to have forms for each type of submission, rather than trying to hide and show the right parts of the forms.  Unless you have a method for abstracting the data (which sections to show ) from the logic ( how to show/unshow them ) it ends up being a mess, just like the OPs original Fiddle.

My fiddle creates a lot more html, but the javascript is as simple as:

```
$('.btn-primary').click( function(){
    $( '.btn-primary').removeClass( 'currentButton' )
    $( this).addClass('currentButton') 
    $( 'form' ).hide()
    $( "#form_" + $(this).attr('id') ).show();
})
```

Also added a bit of cleanup, just for fun.

Of course the most sophisticated implementation of this would probably be heavily integrated into the server side code and be generated a lot more dynamically, but for the purposes of answering the question, this technique seems more straight forward and more capable (note how easy it is to add additional content, like the headers I added to each form.  IT would be equally easy to add descriptive text, disparate form elements, etc).

Comment: Yeah.. I added the submit show button but instead of showing as four textbox when I click Process button, it is showing only three textbox.. Can you provide a jsfilddle example ?

Comment: But you're not still not `show()`ing the `'#value'` textbox in that section.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfilddle example if possible? Looks to me something stupid I am doing for sure..

Comment: Can you explain why you're removing and adding different textboxes?

Comment: That's my requirement.. Right? Once I click INSERT button, I would like to show three textbox as shown above. And if I click UPDATE button, I would like to show three same textbox again.. But If I click delete button, I would like to show only node textbox and then lastly if I click PROCESS button, I would like to show four textbox as shown above.. So to do this I was adding and removing stuff.. May be not an elegant solution.. this is what I came up in couple of minutes.. :(

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you're not using 4 different forms... I'm not sure how you expect this to act at submission time.  I see you're using bootstrap ... should this question be tagged bootstrap perhaps?

Comment: Once I submit this form, all the other textbox value should be null other than which is required? Correct And I will store somewhere, ok whether I have clicked Process or Insert or Update or Delete and then depending on that I will process them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49288/discussion-between-ssh-and-dan-farrell)

Comment: `$(document).ready( ... )` wrapper was all that was missing.  Easy mistake, considering jsfiddle more or less silently adds this to your pages for you.

Comment: you still around? look into chat.. one more basic question